# How will this loop work in SystemVerilog language?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, verification

How will this loop work in SystemVerilog language ?

```
for(bit [2:0] i = 0; i < 4; i++)
```

What will be the values of i after each iteration provided i is 3 bit wire ?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: the values will be 0, 1, 2, 3, provided that the loop is in the right context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bit [2:0] i;
```

As **i** is 3-bit value, it can take values from 0-7.

so **i** will get values 0,1,2,3

Comment: 3 bit values can hold 0-7

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Regarding the [first revision of your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56053633/1), it looks like you're linking to your own website. You **must** disclose this fact in future, else your answer may be deleted as spam. Please take a moment to read Stack Overflow's [self-promotion policy](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).